# TypeError: Cannot read property 'crud_name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

hello I am trying to save data into mongodb using nodejs but it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'crud_name' of undefined
>       at insertRecord (D:\nodejs\node_web\controllers\crudController.js:18:28)
>       at router.post (D:\nodejs\node_web\controllers\crudController.js:12:6)

controller:

```
  router.get('/crud',(req, res) => {
res.render("crud", {crud : new Crud(), newCrud : true});
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    insertRecord(req, res);
});

function insertRecord(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
var crud = new Crud();
crud.crud_name = req.body.crud_name;
crud.crud_email = req.body.crud_email;
crud.crud_mobile = req.body.crud_mobile;
// Save methods
crud.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err)
      res.redirect('crud');
    else {
        console.log('Error during record insertions : ' + err);
    }
});
}
```

schema:

```
   var crudSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

crud_name: {
    type: String
},

crud_email: {
    type: String
},

crud_mobile: {
    type: String
}

 });

  mongoose.model('Crud', crudSchema );
```

form:

```
  <form method="POST" action="/crud">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputAddress">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="crud_name" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="crud_email" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Mobile</label>
    <input type="number" name="crud_mobile" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Enter your mobile">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It clearly says that your  `req.body` is undefined.

Comment: sory m new to it can u plz show me how to define it?

Comment: Are you using `body-parser`

Comment: @Mr.Bhat no ,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Thats why your form data is not getting parsed properly

Comment: You have to use bodyparser middleware in your index(server).js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run

`npm i body-parser`

Add these to your `app.js / main.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//This will serve parsing for the whole application.
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Rest of the code
```

Read more about body-parser here 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: hi can u plz tell me why m getting this error: ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\node_web\views\crud\index.ejs:14
    12|   </thead>

    13|   <tbody>

 >> 14|     <% cruds.forEach(function (crud) { %>

    15|     <tr>

    16|       <td><%= crud.crud_name %></td>

    17|       <td></td>


cruds is not defined

Comment: this is its controller router.get('/', (req, res) => { 
 Crud.find((err, docs) => { 
  if (!err) { res.render("crud", {
              cruds: docs
          });
   } else { 
    console.log('Error in retrieving employee list :' + err);
     } 
   }); 
});

Comment: complete format code:  paste.ofcode.org/Z6VbewYTvFLajpvGkAGmKE

Comment: this is my current code, same error paste.ofcode.org/fREpHrB7iw4yw6YVxFkZ3Z

Comment: yes this is right ejs file its name is index.ejs in a folder named crud

Comment: Just console log your controller result and see whether its returning anything or just undefined !

Comment: I write console.log(cruds); and stil undefined

Comment: thats the reason you get error while rendering ejs file. Just check for undefined in ejs before trying to loop thru it 
`<% if (cruds.length) { %>`
`... <!--add your loop here -->`
`<% } %>`

Comment: sory its still same